# Create a TTF in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, truetype

Is there a way to create a True Type Font file programmatically in `objective-c`? I found this reference, http://developer.apple.com/fonts/TTRefMan/index.html, but it doesn't seem there are any built in methods to accomplish this.

Suggestions?  Guidance?

Comment: There certainly isn't a system API to create TTF (or OpenType, the modern successor) files. It's not a common need; font files are normally output by font design applications, which probably use proprietary frameworks to do this.

Comment: The best way is to download the ttf file from internet and then use it in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any procedural font creation code.

Your best bet would be to start with FontForge: http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I know it's possible since the app MyFont: [http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myfont/id380824731](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myfont/id380824731?mt=8) does it.

Anyone figured out how?